# How can I show files being downloaded in WinSCP .NET assembly from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have a script that downloads some recordings from an FTP server and the downloads are saved in a folder inside a local path on my computer.

I have been able to trigger a message when all the recordings have been downloaded successfully, but I wanted instead to display a message every time each of the FTP recordings are downloaded. How can I do that?

This is the script:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"

$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = "ip of ftp"
    PortNumber = port number
    UserName = "user"
    Password = "credentials"
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    
    $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
    $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary
 
    $transferResult =
        $session.GetFiles($remotePath, $localPath, $False, $transferOptions)
 
    $transferResult.Check()

    foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
    {
        Write-Host ("Download of {0} succeeded" -f $transfer.FileName)
    }
}
finally
{
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

I have looked for ways to do it but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show just the names of the files as they finish transferring, use [`Session.FileTransferred` event](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_filetransferred):

```
function FileTransferred
{
    param($e)
 
    if ($e.Error -eq $Null)
    {
        Write-Host "Download of $($e.FileName) succeeded"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Download of $($e.FileName) failed: $($e.Error)"
    }
}

$session.add_FileTransferred( { FileTransferred($_) } )

$session.Open($sessionOptions)

...

$session.GetFiles($remotePath, $localPath, $False, $transferOptions).Check()
```

---

If you want to display progress of individual file transfers, you can use [`Session.FileTransferProgress`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_filetransferprogress).